# Save InputStream to ByteArray

Tags: java, sockets, encoding

My task is: 
Clients connect to ServerSocket and send files with any encoding what they want(UTF-8, ISO-8859-5, CP1251 e.g.). 
When Server receive file content, script must insert it into MySQL.

As the encoding can be different, I need save file content like ByteArray(?).

Byt I dont know how get ByteArray from Socket.getInputStream().

Please help with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
int ret = 0;

while((ret = inputStream.read(tmp)) > 0)
{
    bos.write(tmp, 0, ret);
}

byte[] myArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: One more question. How I can send to client document like byte array to Socket OutputStream without specifying encoding?

Comment: I figured out... OutputStream OS = DataTransferSocket.getOutputStream(); and then OS.write(FileContent); in byte array. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

Commons IO - http://commons.apache.org/io/

`toByteArray(Reader input, String encoding)`
          Get the contents of a Reader as a byte[] using the specified character encoding.

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: I cant use this, because server dont know what encoding client use.

Comment: @user857923: try `toByteArray(InputStream input)` (also from Commons IO IOUtils) instead.